# setup project with mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, installation

I have a project I have a WinForm program written in c #, which has been completed. I use MySQL as if it were a database. When we install this program to the customers do not need to install mysqli automatically, how can we not install it?

Comment: It sounds like your application only needs to know what the settings are to connect to the MySQL instance and the DLL required to interact with the database.  You'll need to give your customers a mechanism for specifying which database to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

for what you are saying you only need to create a connection string to your connection:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-without-dsn.html

just make sure your installation includes odbc drivers for MySQL